# Django use query arguments in POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view which is supposed to send an email to a bunch of users when its submitted.

I am using a Form for entering the email contents and then sending the email to users from the database based on the query arguments to the URL.

I'm doing it this way because the users are selected on a separate page.
So the url looks something like `/sendmail/?users=18,21,32`. Because I'm using a form, my view in inherited from `FormView` and my emailing code is in `form_valid`.

The problem is that I can't seem to access the query arguments from that function.  `self.request.GET` is empty and `self.request.POST` only has the form field values.

The method I think I should be using is to add a hidden `users` field to the form (type `ModelMultipleChoiceField`), which I populate from the url query.

The problem is I can't figure out how to do this.
I tried re-implementing `get_initial` like this, but it didn't seem to do anything:

```
def get_initial(self):
    if 'users' in self.request.GET:
        users = self.request.GET['users'].split(',')
        return {'users': User.objects.filter(pk__in=users)}
```

Is this the right approach, or is there a better way?  If the approach is right, then what am I doing wrong?

I'm hiding the field using the following definition:

```
users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput(),
                                       required=False)
```

**EDIT:**  A bit more experimentation, and it seems to work if I don't hide the `users` form field.  So it seems like initial data is not populated to hidden fields?

Comment: How do you hide the field from the form, can you show the form code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern to fetch get params, it will handle non-existant parameters.

```
/myview/?users=18,21,32

def myview(request):
    users = request.GET.get('users', None)
    if users:
        user_ids = users.split(',')
```

If the params is not there, you must be calling it the wrong way

Comment: The parameters are there, but only before posting, and they don't seem to be populated into the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing [`request.REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST) into the form as the data, rather than `request.POST` - `REQUEST` includes data from both POST and GET.